# Why Enum singleton are serialization safe?

Tags: java, serialization, enums, deserialization, hashcode

Internally how serialization / deserialization  take place in Enum ? How can jvm generates the same hashcode before ( serialization  ) and after (deserialization   ) ?

Answer (score 7):

Serialization treats `enum`s specially. Basically, it stores only a reference to its `class` and the name of the constant. Upon deserialization, this information is used to lookup the existing runtime object of the `enum` type.

Thus, if you deserialize the `enum` constant within the same runtime, you will get the same runtime instance you have serialized.

However, when deserializing in another JVM, the hashcode might be different. But having the same hashcode is not a required criteria for singletons. The important point is to never have another instance of the class and this is guaranteed as the serialization implementation will never create an instance of an `enum` type but only lookup existing constants.

Answer (score 2):

> Internally how serialization / deserialization take place in Enum ?

You can't serialize enums in Java.  You can only serialize a reference to an Enum.  This means if your enum has any private fields they will not be written nor restored.

> How can jvm generates the same hashcode before ( serialization ) and after (deserialization ) ?

Exactly how a JVM generates hashCode is not specified in the JLS and in fact in the source code where is multiple implementations.  However, the Oracle 8 update 45 JVM generates the same hashCodes in the same order after restart.

```
Object[] objs = new Object[5];
for(int i=0;i<objs.length;i++) {
    objs[i] = new Object();
}
RetentionPolicy[] values = RetentionPolicy.values();
System.out.println(objs+": "+objs.hashCode());
for (Object obj : objs) {
    System.out.println(obj+": "+obj.hashCode());
}
for (RetentionPolicy policy : values) {
    System.out.println(policy+": "+policy.hashCode());
}
```

If you run this with `new Object[5]` it prints

```
[Ljava.lang.Object;@677327b6: 1735600054
java.lang.Object@14ae5a5: 21685669
java.lang.Object@7f31245a: 2133927002
java.lang.Object@6d6f6e28: 1836019240
java.lang.Object@135fbaa4: 325040804
java.lang.Object@45ee12a7: 1173230247
SOURCE: 856419764
CLASS: 621009875
RUNTIME: 1265094477
```

If I reduce the array size to 2 it prints.

```
[Ljava.lang.Object;@677327b6: 1735600054
java.lang.Object@14ae5a5: 21685669
java.lang.Object@7f31245a: 2133927002
SOURCE: 1836019240
CLASS: 325040804
RUNTIME: 1173230247
```

Note how it is producing the same hashCodes in the same order.  If I comment out the `Object[]` code completely.

```
SOURCE: 1735600054
CLASS: 21685669
RUNTIME: 2133927002
```

The reason you are seeing the same hashCodes each time you run your program is that it is creating the same number of hashCodes before checking the hashCodes of your enums.

Note: an Object doesn't have a system hashCode until you ask for it to reduce the cost of creating objects.

Answer (score 0):

I have written a simple enum class.
for ex:

```
public enum EnumTest{
    
    IND(1),
    ORG(2);
    
    int deger;
    
    EnumTest(int deger){
        this.deger = deger;
    }
    
}
```

After we have compiled this enum class, we may use javap tool using javap EnumTest command.

```
  public final class EnumTest extends java.lang.Enum{
    public static final EnumTest IND;
    public static final EnumTest ORG;
    int deger;
    public static EnumTest[] values();
    public static EnumTest valueOf(java.lang.String);
    static {};
}
```

As you can see above text generated by javap tool, enum instances are static and static variables can not serialize.

Comment: It's helpful if you can select the text generated from the console and paste that, rather than an image, so that it can be read by e.g. screen readers and those who choose to use different/larger fonts.